# Setting up a new front-end development environment

Tags: html, macos, frontend

I'm relatively new to code so please bear with me if this is a noob question.  I develop on a Mac OS with Ruby on Rails.  All of my setup on my Mac is with Rails so setting up a project using it is easy.

But now, I'm working on a project where I'll be using a Bootstrap template to code the front-end and then will be passing off the code to a developer not using Ruby on Rails.

My main question is, what program can I install to be able to do just front end HTML, CSS, Bootstrap without all of the RoR backend setup so I can easily transfer the code and don't have to setup a RoR app?  I obviously would need a development environment still to see my revised code.

Appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install Ruby on Rails or even Ruby if you are only working with HTML, CSS and Bootstrap. There isn't any program that you need to install to run HTML & CSS.

1. Just create a different directory, create a file called index.html, index.css.
2. Add the CDN for bootstrap and link the CSS.
3. Open the index.html and you will see the webpage.

I do not understand why you are brining Ruby on Rails into your question, so if I miss understood your question, please let me know!